# Unicode characters in math mode in pdfLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I can't write Unicode characters in math mode. All current answers for this topic for other typsetting systems, not for pdfLaTeX.

I want to use Unicode in my formula. Even I used `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, my code gives error:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Çıkış sıcaklığı
$$T_{çıkış}$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `T_{\text{çıkış}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the correct syntax. Anyway, it is a word you want to have subscripted, not the succession of $5$ variables. This works:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Çıkış sıcaklığı
\[ T_{\text{çıkış}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Comment aside*: use the LaTeX syntax `\[ ... \]` for displayed equations, not the plain TeX `$$ ... $$`, which yields bad spacing. Also, you should  load `hyperref` as the last package(very few exceptions).