# How can I show S-comma in LaTeX math mode?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, amsmath, unicode, characters

I am writing my bachelor's thesis and it needs to be written in Romanian. While writing some math formula, I wanted to write "and". It translates to "și". As it turns out, my [LaXeTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX#Example) compiler can't render the ș (S-comma).

This is my code:

```tex
\begin{align}
       & \mathlarger{Fie\quad X(N) = x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{N-1}} \\
       & \mathlarger{unde\ N \in \mathbb{N} \ și\ k \in \{0,1,2,\dots,N/2\}} \\
       & \mathlarger{Avem:}
\end{align}
```

and this is the output:

[image: Output of the above code]

How might I be able to show that S-comma?

Comment: I did post an answer but please  always include a test file not just a fragment, especially one using non standard commands that are not defined by default, such as `\mathlarger`

Comment: Thank you! It's my first question here, I didn't know. I'll be keeping this in mind the next time I have a question.

Comment: For crosslinking, special case of [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex/). // Actually duplicate of [amsmath - Unicode characters in math mode in pdfLaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434659/unicode-characters-in-math-mode-in-pdflatex) (funnily there **is** a `ş` there as well) but this one got more ↑ now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Words, even without accents should not be in math italic, so

`\text{unde}` and `\text{și}`

Comment: Wouldn’t `\text` be a better recommendation? We usually want inter-formula text to reflect the outside text font.

Comment: @Gaussler yes probably,I'll update

Answer (score 4):

In addition to rendering text-type words that may appear in a math expression in *text mode* (via a `\text` directive, say), you may want to execute a single `\large` instruction *before* entering math mode instead of executing `\mathlarger` at the start of every singe row in the `align` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}  % optional
%\usepackage{relsize} % for \mathlarger macro, not needed below
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \text macro and align env.
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for \mathbb macro
\counterwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}           % just for this example

\par 
\begingroup
\large % <-- execute this *before* entering display math mode
\begin{align}
       & \text{Fie}\quad X(N) = x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{N-1} \\
       & \text{unde $N \in \mathbb{N}$ și $k \in \{0,1,2,\dots,N/2\}$} \\
       & \text{Avem:}
\end{align}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the `\begingroup\large` you recommend would have very adverse effects on the text preceding the display, assuming that no blank line appears in between.

Comment: @egreg - I've thrown in a `\par` directive and and an extra blank line. I realize that this approach conflicts with the general stricture against starting off display math material with a paragraph break. In the present case, though, this conflict may be the least of several evils, given that `\large` is supposed to prevail for the math material...

Comment: Sorry,  but the cure is worse than the disease. By the way, I see no reason whatsoever for making equations bigger.

Comment: @egreg - What would be your preferred alternative? (FWIW, I can also see no reason whatsoever for increasing the font size for the three lines in question.)

Comment: See answer to know how I'd do it.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want larger font size in the display, you can avoid `\mathlarger`, but I'd not do it: a math display is already prominent enough.

In any case, you need `\text` for textual parts in math material.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288889/4427
% detach \eqref processing from \tag processing
\let\tagform@ref\tagform@
\let\maketag@@@ref\maketag@@@
\patchcmd{\eqref}{\tagform@}{\tagform@ref}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tagform@ref}{\maketag@@@}{\maketag@@@ref}{}{}
% redefine \tagform@ to use the current size
\def\tagform@#1{%
  \maketag@@@{\saved@size(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
% in general \saved@size does nothing
\def\saved@size{}

% now we define a wrapper
\NewDocumentEnvironment{largerdisplay}{O{\large}mb}
 {% #1 = desired size (default \large), #2 = type of display, #3 = body
  \protected@edef\saved@size{\fontsize{\f@size}{0}\selectfont}%
  $$\begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}
  \abovedisplayskip=0.8ex \belowdisplayskip=\z@
  #1\noindent
  \begin{#2}#3\end{#2}%
  \end{minipage}$$}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{largerdisplay}{align}
  & \text{Fie } X(N) = x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{N-1} \\
  & \text{unde }N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ și } k \in \{0,1,2,\dots,N/2\} \\
  & \text{Avem:}
\end{largerdisplay}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with the simple `align`:

[image]